# How can I start/stop a DisplayLink when a CALayer is on/offscreen?

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, core-animation

I'm making an animation in a CALayer that needs to update smoothly over time. I tried the following approaches:

- **CADisplayLink for iOS, CVDisplayLink for OS X**, plus calling `setNeedsDisplay` from the callback
- **CABasicAnimation** for a custom `displayTime` property, with `fromValue=0`, `toValue=1`, `duration=1`, `repeatCount=HUGE_VALF`, `cumulative=YES`, and `needsDisplayForKey:@"displayTime"` returning YES.

These both work to draw the animation, but I'm not sure which is better. **Does Core Animation internally use a display link for updating animations?**

Furthermore, neither of these allow me to know when the layer comes onscreen or is offscreen. Even the animation continues to run when the NSWindow is closed (`-drawInContext:` is continuously called). The `kCAOnOrderOut` action is not triggered, nor is `-setHidden:` called. **How can the layer tell when it is on or offscreen?**